# For loop populating Immutable map with null data points from zero index

Tags: angular, immutable.js, ngrx

I'm using ngrx store with immutable to handle data in my angular 2 app. I have a reducer converting the data from a successful API call into the immutable store's map of id's to objects: `sessions: Map<number, ISession>`. To convert from the native array `ISession[]` in `action.payload` I perform a foreach loop, in a withMutations call:

```
case SessionsActions.LOAD_SESSIONS_SUCCESS:
  return state.withMutations(map => {
    map.set('loading', false);

    action.payload.forEach((session: ISession) => {
      console.log("Setting ",session);
      map.setIn(['sessions', session.id], session );
    });
  }) as ISessions;
```

I get the expected console output, of four items:

```
Setting  Object {id: 6, payslip: null, invlice: null, paidByClient: false, completed: false…}
Setting  Object {id: 8, payslip: null, invlice: 1, paidByClient: true, completed: false…}
Setting  Object {id: 9, payslip: 1, invlice: 1, paidByClient: true, completed: false…}
Setting  Object {id: 7, payslip: null, invlice: null, paidByClient: false, completed: false…}
```

but the store is filled with 10 items, it's populating the id's from 0 with nulls up to the maximum (9) where the data itself is stored:

[image]

Any idea why this behavior is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by constructing the map manually and setting it using `set` rather than `setIn`:

```
  case SessionsActions.LOAD_SESSIONS_SUCCESS:
  var state = state.withMutations(map => {
    map.set('loading', false);

    var sessions = Map<String, ISession>();
    for (var i = 0; i < action.payload.length; i++)
    {
      var session = action.payload[i];
      sessions = sessions.set(session.id, session );
    }
    map.set('sessions', sessions);
  }) as ISessions;
```

I assume it's some bug with the `withMutations` function.